# How to Convert D3DCOLORVALUE to delphi tcolor

Tags: c++, delphi, tcolor

I have a list of integers, obtained through C ++ code and which representing different D3DCOLORVALUE ambient, etc...

What is the correct method to obtain the same colors, from this numbers, in Delphi?.

For example, using a program in C ++ (Visual Studio 2012), by calling a library routine in C ++ (separate dll file) I can obtain the following values:

```
-1.44852785e-016 = 2770796799 (represent the color)
 1.57844226e+11  = 1376977151 (represent the color)
-1.98938735e+034 = 4168431103 (represent the color)
 3.39617733e+038 = 4294967295 (represent the color)
```

@Rudy Velthuis, The original code is: (some values contained in the array are those shown above)

```
int32_t index = ifcObject->indicesForFaces[0];

uint32_t    ambient  = ((int32_t*) vertices)[index * (vertexElementSize / sizeof(float)) + 6],
            diffuse  = ((int32_t*) vertices)[index * (vertexElementSize / sizeof(float)) + 7],
            emissive = ((int32_t*) vertices)[index * (vertexElementSize / sizeof(float)) + 8],
            specular = ((int32_t*) vertices)[index * (vertexElementSize / sizeof(float)) + 9];
```

Then in Delphi XE6 using

```
PInteger (@ColorsArray [index * sizeOfVertices + 6])^
```

I get the same values but, in delphi the colors are black or null. Sometimes negative numbers are obtained, it is understood that in C ++ it is possible to represent a color with a negative value but in delphi does not work.

How can I convert a color value, obtained in D3DCOLORVALUE format, to a Delphi's TColor?

That the values are used to obtain the colors of objects in
D3DMATERIAL9, D3DCOLORVALUE Ambient (Ambient color RGB)

```
FLOAT r;
FLOAT g;
FLOAT b;
FLOAT a;
```

This function make the color:

```
void    SetColor(
                D3DCOLORVALUE   * iColor,
                uint32_t        color
            )
{
    iColor->r = (float) (color & ((unsigned int) 255 * 256 * 256 * 256)) / (256 * 256 * 256);
    iColor->r /= 255.f;

    iColor->g = (float) (color & (255 * 256 * 256)) / (256 * 256);
    iColor->g /= 255.f;

    iColor->b = (float) (color & (255 * 256)) / 256;
    iColor->b /= 255.f;

    iColor->a = (float) (color & (255));
    iColor->a /= 255.f;
}
```

But in Delphi it does not work, the color obtained is wrong.

Comparison of colors with the @Dsm solution:

Left: Color obtained Right: Desired color

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

I have made a simple example to illustrate the differences:

[image]

The first color corresponds to the foot of the column and the second color corresponds to the column. The figure with the platform is the example with the library viewer, with the correct colors for that version and the figure on the right is an image of the watch in Visual Studio 2012 to show that the content of the array is the same and the value obtained with the cast is also the same but, when converting these numbers to colors they do not give the same result.

Comment: C++ standard library doesn't contain a single thing related to graphics, so it has no notion of color. What library did you use to get the values?

Comment: Casting a floating point value to a `int32_t *` (IOW, to a pointer!) is pretty suspicious. Who on earth wrote that code?

Comment: From [Lights and Materials (Direct3D 9)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174694(v=vs.85).aspx) : *`Ambient light color takes the form of an RGBA value, where each component is an integer value from 0 to 255. This is unlike most color values in Direct3D.`*

Comment: If that was your original code, why didn't you post that instead of the weird and probably wrong cast to `int32*`? The original code casts a pointer to, well, a pointer, assuming that `vertices` is an array, and not a float to a pointer.

Comment: @LURD: those are the named colours. But any combination of R, G and B is possible.

Comment: ISTM that this is a bitness problem. You probably have to change the bitness of the values obtained. Your `2770796799` is hex `A52700FF` and it looks like that should become `FF0027A5` which should be mostly blue and a little green.

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis, My question is how, the theory I have read it but I need to know how to make the transformation from these numbers, you indicate values but do not indicate how you have obtained them

Comment: @Fisad: `2770796799` decimal is the same as hex `$A52700FF`, but it looks like you need `$FF0027A5`, since that looks like a proper colour with full opacity (alpha = $FF = 255, red = 0, green = $27 = 39, blue = $A5 = 165).

Comment: If I look at the numbers on the right side of the pictures, I guess that these are indices into an array (of colour values). They are certainly not color values on their own.

Comment: `iColor->r = (float) (color & ((unsigned int) 255 * 256 * 256 * 256)) / (256 * 256 * 256);`is the same as: `iColor->r = (float)((color & 0xFF000000) >> 24);`. That is simply reading the single bytes and, in the next step, dividing them by 255. That value is stored as float. So do the opposite, but beware to get the right values from the right index in the array (vertices must be an array, right?)

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, You are right, vertices is an array of floats that contains a sequence of 10 values, the first three for the coordinate, the next 3 for the normal and the last four for the colors of ambient, diffuse, emissive and specular. The function SetColor work good on C++ application. But when I have done the Delphi version the calculations are not equal, I think my error is in the type of variable to store the results. The values of the figures are not important for the analysis, the values that are to the left of the figure on the left, are the values of colors

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, Can you try to translate the SetColor function to pascal language, using a single as input variable and a TColor as output, without considering the reference value of D3DCOLORVALUE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like the original C++ extracts the colour knowing intimately the internal structure of an array of records. In your code you should not use (int32_t*) because that creates a pointer to a constant, and you just want to cast the float to a uint_32_t, so I think what you want to satisfy your test code is just

```
ambient := uint32_t(-1.44852785e-016);
diffuse := uint32_t(1.57844226e+11);
etc;
```

That doesn't compile in Delphi (invalid typecast), so instead you need to do something like

```
var
  p : pointer;
  iFloat : single;
  iColour : TColor;
begin
  iFloat := 1.57844226e+11;
  p := @(iFloat);
  iColour := TColor(p^);
  diffuse := iColour;

end;
```

which gives a red colour.

Note that all your colours appear similar because you are taking the start of several similar addresses.

Expressed as a function this might become

```
function FloatToColor( const pVal : single ) : TColor;
var
  p : pointer;
  iFloat : single;
begin
  iFloat := 1.57844226e+11;
  p := @(iFloat);
  Result := TColor(p^);
end;
```

## Edit

Based on the fact that $FF appears in the wrong place, it occurred to me that these values might be CMYK format. In tests I found that it was a modified CMYK format - more a YMCK format, if you will, so to get the correct colours I had to reverse the roles of red and blue.

There is no true conversion from CMYK to RGB, but the following is approximate.

```
function CMYKtoRGB( const pValue : TColor) : TColor;
var
  c,m,y,k,r,g,b : byte;
begin
  c := GetCValue( pValue );
  m := GetMValue( pValue );
  y := GetYValue( pValue );
  k := GetKValue( pValue );

  //r := $FF xor c;
  r := $FF - c;
  b := $FF - y;
  g := $FF - m;
  if k <> $FF then
  begin
    k := $FF - k;
    r := r * k;
    g := g * k;
    b := b * k;
  end;
  Result := RGB( b, g, r );
end;

function FloatToColor( const pVal : single ) : TColor;
var
  p : pointer;
  iFloat : single;
begin
  iFloat := pVal;
  p := @(iFloat);
  Result := CMYKtoRGB(TColor(p^));
end;
```

Note that I use RGB( b, g, r) rather than the expected RGB( r, g, b) to account for the reversed colour order.

Comment: Close but, I keep getting 10-digit integer values and the colors are wrong, plus there are negative values.

Comment: What colours are you expecting for each value? Rudy suggests that hex is reversed, but I don't think it is quite as simple as that..

Comment: The values indicated above, on the left, are some of the values contained in the array, the values on the right are the values resulting from the cast in C ++. When using your technique when the color should be orange you get a pink to fucsia. Each value on the right is passed some reference through the SetColor function to get the color (uint32_t  color)

Comment: Different shades of orange, yes?

Comment: it's possible. As additional information the float values belong to the configuration of an IFC format file (construction elements), used for BIM analysis.The problem is that I must analyze hundreds of values every time I analyze a file, the values are not static they are dynamic. As far as I can understand the values include the alpha value for transparency

Comment: You are the best man, 90% accurate, the colors are still a bit opaque. I have included an example of the colors obtained and desired, with your solution the darker color is obtained, it would seem that the first color obtained represents the second desired color and the second one obtained represents the first desired color. It looks strange.

Comment: I have communicated with the author of the library and he has told me that the numeric values represent colors in the ARGB format on a normal Windows machine. Like 8 - 8 - 8 - 8 bit i..e A [0..255]. After reading the values through the library, the values are passed to the SetColor function, which I have included above. As you can understand, the values contain the value of alpha as well.

Comment: Your latest proposal results in other colors

Comment: @Fisad - In my tests, using the values you gave,one was grey, the rest were shades of orange. I had to reverse the rgb order in the rgb function because otherwise I got shades of cyan and blue.